# Wine yeast or champagne yeast which will ferment quicker?

Tags: fermentation, yeast

Hello I would want quick method if I use breed yeast the fermentation finish in 7-10 days. But its taste is terrible.

I would like to know, between Champagne and Wine yeast - which one is faster ?

Comment: Depends which strains you want to compare, exactly...

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to ferment, and what you expect at the end. If you ferment all simple sugars, then it can ferment very quickly, if you have lots of complex sugars it can take longer. some strains do better with complex sugars, others with simple sugars.......so please add more details on what you are making.

Comment: I will use grape juice I wont add extra sugar

Answer (score 0):

Flavours from yeast are mostly generated during the initial part of fermentation, this is known as the "lag phase" - when the yeast is quickly multiplying.  Pitching too little yeast means the yeast has to reproduce many more times, resulting in a more significant yeast flavour.

The question seems to suggest that the wine was only allowed 1 week of "primary" fermentation, whereas typically there's 1-2 weeks of "secondary" fermentation after this.

So it's not exactly what the OP is asking, but use *either* wine yeast.  Ferment it at the warmer end of the yeast's specified temperature range.  With a well-prepared must it will normally finish *primary* ferment in 5-7 days.  But then **wait**!  Give the yeast another week (or 2) to finish up.  During this *secondary* phase, the yeast is re-absorbing (or otherwise processing) many of the off flavours that are a normal by-product of fermentation.

Here's some suggestions to ensure a good ferment:

- Ensure you use absolute best-practice sanitation procedures.
- Aerate your wine-must before pitching yeast
- Pitch an adequate amount of quality wine yeast (it depends on the yeast)
- Add some yeast nutrient
- Keep the ferment in an appropriate temperature range for the yeast (If you don't know, try 18-22 degree C)

There are also some extra ways to get off flavours:

- Fermenting too warm
- Not allowing the fermentaion to complete (where the yeast re-absorbs by-products)
- Not enough oxygen initially (which the yeast use for re-production)
- Poor sanitation, resulting in wild yeast and/or bacteria in the ferment